# Is it possible to find an operator $T:C(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow C(\mathbb{R})$ such that $T=N+D$, where $N$ is nilpotent and $D$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $C(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all continuous functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

I want to find a linear operator $T:C(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow C(\mathbb{R})$, proper subspaces $W_{1}, W_{2}$ of $C(\mathbb{R})$ such that $C(\mathbb{R})=W_{1}\oplus W_{2}$ and $T|_{W_{1}}$ is nilpotent $( T|_{W_{1}}\neq 0)$ and $T|_{W_{2}}$ is invertible.

I've tried [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106791/a-question-about-the-multiplication-operator), but it didn't work.

Thanks for your kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on the other answers, I'll just note that this can be done constructively.

Let $f_1, f_2$ be any continuous functions with $f_1(1) = f_2(2) = 1$, $f_1(2) = f_2(1) = 0$.  (For example, $f_1(x) = 2-x$, $f_2(x)=x-1$.)  Set $W_1 = \mathrm{span}\{f_1, f_2\}$, and $W_2 = \{ f \in C(\mathbb{R}) : f(1) = f(2) = 0\}$.  Then $C(\mathbb{R}) = W_1 \oplus W_2$: if $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$, we can write $$f = (f(1) f_1 + f(2) f_2) + (f - f(1) f_1 - f(2) f_2).$$  We can then define
$$Tf = f - f(1) f_1 - f(2) f_2 + f(1) f_2$$
and it is easy to check that $T$ has the desired properties.

Comment: Eldrege: A clarification. If $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$, then it can be write in only one way: $f=g_{1}+g_{2}$, where $g_{1}\in W_{1}$ and $g_{2}\in W_{2}$. So,  we define $T(f)=f(1)f_{2}+g_{2}$? The function $f_{2}$ is the one which you defined above.

Comment: @spohreis: You're right.  I fixed it.  Note that, as I pointed out, we can write $g_1, g_2$ explicitly in terms of $f$ as $g_1 = f(1) f_1 + f(2) f_2$ and $g_2 = f - g_1 = f - f(1) f_1 - f(2) f_2$.

Answer (score 3):

Take any non-zero $f_1, f_2\in C(\mathbb{R})$. Consder $W_1=\operatorname{span}\{f_1,f_2\}$. Since $W_1$ is finite dimensional there exist $W_2$ such that $W_1\oplus W_2=C(\mathbb{R})$. Define $N :W_1\to W_1$ by equalities $N(f_1)=f_2$, $N(f_2)=0$ and define $D:W_2\to W_2$ to be identity operator. Then 
$T=N\oplus D$ is desired operator.

Answer (score 2):

If by "operator" you mean $\mathbb{R}$-linear endomorphism, the answer is certainly yes.  We may write $C(R) = W_1 \oplus W_2$ where $W_1$ is $2$-dimensional, with basis $e_1, e_2$.  (This may require the Axiom of Choice).  Let $T(e_1) = e_2$, $T(e_2) = 0$ and let $T$ be the identity on $W_2$.